# ZODBGroupManager vs portal_groups - any problems using both?

Tags: plone, plone-3.x

I've seen that I can do pretty much the same with them about creating and editing groups: but when I change a group title (not id) programatically, the title I changed is only shown on `prefs_groups_overview` (and at `/Plone/acl_users/source_groups/manage_workspace`) when I use `ZODBGroupManager.updateGroup` to change it: using `portal_groups.editGroup` it changes the title, but isn't reflected on those two urls I provided.

Which should I use? Are there any problems using portal_groups to add groups and ZODBGroupManager to edit it's titles since ZODBGroupManager is the only one that changes the titles in the urls above? Will I have problems using both of them?

(I'm using Plone 3.3.5. This bug [has been fixed](http://dev.plone.org/plone/ticket/7277) on 4.X. (`prefs_groups_overview`), but I would like to know if there are problems using ZODBGroupManager since I'm stuck with 3.3.5.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One is a PAS plugin (ZODBGroupManager) that ships with PAS (the [Pluggable Auth service](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.PluggableAuthService/1.7.5)). The other is a portal tool (portal_groups) that ships with [PlonePAS](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.PlonePAS/4.0.8) (a collection of code and PAS plugins that are Plone-specific.)

You can think of portal_groups as "higher up" and ZODBGroupManager as "lower down" (in the software stack) if that helps (because the former is a portal tool that has a UI representation in Plone, whereas the latter does not).

Via that "high/low" logic, you could say portal_groups is "better" because it's managed by Plone. But I would personally use either/or however you see fit, and not worry too much about problems.